# jQuery – <tbody> replacement at page bottom causes page scroll

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, dom, scroll, replace

I need to replace a `<tbody>` element. I am using jQuery v1.8.2’s `.html()` method.

My `<tbody>` element is at the bottom of a page.

IE8 and FF’s latest version are working as expected, but Chrome does a weird thing. As soon as `$('tbody').html('new value')` is called, `<tbody>` disappears (as expected), but then the `document.body` element shrinks and causes page scroll. After that, the new `<tbody>` appears back with new values.

I don't want `document.body`’s extra shrinking, which causes page scrolling. I want the page to hold still when I am replacing `<tbody>`’s content.

Can this problem be handled somehow?

Caching and resetting `$('body').scrollTop()` is not an option.

Comment: How about adding a `height` to the table equal to it's current height, do your stuff, then remove it?

Comment: that actually did the trick, thank you!